# How to register a GameObject with Zenject's IOC container

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

The [Zenject documentation](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject#scene-bindings) shows adding a component to a `GameObject` looking like:

[image]

However mine looks like:

[image]

How come mine appears to add a Collection of `GameObject`s rather than a single GameObject?  I also show an `Identifier` whereas the example doesn't have that and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the images in the documentation are out of date.  The Component property was changed to a list, so if you add your component to the list it will function the same as the previous Component property.  As for the Identifier, that is optional and can be ignored if you are not interested in using it.